# How can I change specific recurring text on a very large HTML file?

Tags: html, regex

I have a very big HTML file (talking about 20MB) and I need to remove from the file a large amount of nodes of the form:

```
<tr><td>SPECIFIC-STRING</td><td>RANDOM-STRING</td><td>RANDOM-STRING</td></tr><tr><td style="padding-top:0" colspan="3">RANDOM-STRING</td></tr>
```

The file I need to work on is basically made of thousands of these strings, and I only need to remove those that have a specific first string, for instance, all those with the first string being "banana":

```
<tr><td>banana</td><td>RANDOM-STRING</td><td>RANDOM-STRING</td></tr><tr><td style="padding-top:0" colspan="3">RANDOM-STRING</td></tr>
```

I tried achieving this opening the file in Geany and using the replace feature with this regex:

```
<tr><td>banana<\/td><td>(.*)<\/td><td>(.*)<\/td><\/tr><tr><td(.*)<\/td><\/tr>
```

but the console output was that it removed X amount of occurrences, when I know there are way more occurrences than that in the file.
Firefox, Chrome and Brackets fail even to view the html code of the file due to it's size. I can't think of another way to do this due to my large unexperience with HTML.

Comment: You might have to figure out a way to do this in the terminal in a manner that minimizes the memory overhead of loading the file.  How, might I ask, did you end up with a 20MB HTML file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could be using a stream editor which as the name suggest streams the file content, thus never loads the whole file into the main memory.

A popular editor is [`sed`](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html). It does support RegEx.

Your command would have the following structure.

```sh
sed -i -E 's/SEARCH_REGEX/REPLACEMENT/g' INPUTFILE
```

- `-E` for support of extended RegEx
- `-i` for in-place editing mode
- `s` denotes that you want to replace values
- `g` is for `global`. By default `sed` would only replace the first occurrence so to replace all occrrences you must provide `g`
- `SEARCH_REGEX` is the RegEx you need to find the substrings you want to replace
- `REPLACEMENT` is the value you want to replace all matches with
- `INPUTFILE` is the file `sed` is gonna read line-by line and do the replacement for you.

Answer (score 0):

While regex may not be the best tool to do this kinda job, try this adjustment to your pattern:

`<tr><td>banana<\/td><td>(.*?)<\/td><td>(.*?)<\/td><\/tr><tr><td(.*?)<\/td><\/tr>`

That's making your `.*` matches lazy.  I am wondering if those patterns are consuming too much.